# Bootstrap licence free template

Tags: java, templates, bootstrap

I´m creating a new website. For that I´m using a free bootstrap template. On top of my index page I have:

```
 A Design by W3layouts
    Author: W3layout
    Author URL: http://w3layouts.com
    License: Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 Unported
    License URL: http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/
```

Can I delete or change this for my own purpose (in other words change author, License, etc)?

Licence also says:

You are free to:

Share — copy and redistribute the material in any medium or format Adapt — remix, transform, and build upon the material for any purpose, even commercially. The licensor cannot revoke these freedoms as long as you follow the license terms.

So, can I have any problem in future (which clearly I´m not seeing)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot alter that license. The license is granted by the copyright owner, and you're not the copyright owner. This is a legal restriction, and hence does not need to be repeated in the license itself.

Answer (score -1):

You can't change the license. You should check the license policy before downloading it. It is legally prohibited to make any kind of changes in license or copyright and you can't change anything unless it is clearly mentioned in copyright. For more details regarding license policy please refer the links below:

1. https://creativecommons.org/get-cc-savvy/copyright-creativecommons-are-friends/
2. https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/